# Real points in a matrix interval

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, algebraic-geometry, positive-definite

Given $A$ and $B$, two $n \times n$ complex Hermitian positive semidefinite matrices such that $A< B$. I want to show existence (or non existence) of a **real** symmetric positive matrix $X$ such that
\begin{equation}
0\le A\le X \le B.
\end{equation}
What is the most constrictive way to generate examples of $X$?

My Approach: It is clear that $X$ lies between real parts of $A$ and $B$ respectively. So natural choice is to take some convex combination of these real parts. Problem is, the resulting matrix may not satisfy the above inequality involving complex matrices $A$ and $B$. Further, I can cook up examples in $2 \times 2$ case, where such interval may not contain any real matrix, but contains complex matrices.

So the question once again: Given $A$ and $B$ complex Hermitian positive semi-definite, what is the algorithm which guarantees an output positive real matrix $X$ satisfying above inequality.

Comment: What about $\frac{1}{2}(A+B)$?

Comment: @sinbadh Wait. The OP wants $X$ to be **real**.

Comment: $X$ does not always exist (e.g. when $A=B$ is non-real).

Comment: @user1551 That is a trivial case, is't it? I think I should have included strict inequality $A<B$. Problem is, even in that case, I can cook up examples where real $X$ does not exists. Of course, it is only for $2 \times 2$ matrices, and by solving a boring set of inequalities. I want a more elegant method.

Comment: @RSG That's a trivial case, but by continuity, even when $B\ne A$, if $B$ is sufficiently close to $A$ and $A$ is non-real, then then you cannot get a feasible $X$. What I was trying to say is that no algorithm can *guarantee* a solution $X$ because this is an optimisation problem that is not always solvable.

Comment: @user1551 Sorry, I misunderstood it. I have zero knowledge when it comes to optimisation problems. Translating things from one subject to another may be complected. But can you give me some reference where such problem has been discussed? If some theory on existence or non existence of solution for some very special cases there, it may help me.

Comment: @RSG I stand corrected. it's *not* exactly an optimisation problem (because all you need is to find a solution in the feasible region, without using any objective function), but you can turn it into one. I guess this is somewhat related to semidefinite programming, but I'll let the experts speak.